# Selenium webdriver -> closing my chrome after one second

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have issue with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\Mariusz\\anaconda3\\envs\\pgg\\Lib\\site-packages\\chromedriver_binary\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked successfully")
driver.quit()
import chromedriver_binary

wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Above code starting my Chrome for 1 second and then immediately close.

I have feedback in Anaconda:

```
Chrome Browser Invoked successfully
```

And debug:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call
last) Input In [25], in <cell line: 12>()
      9 driver.quit()
     10 import chromedriver_binary
---> 12 wd = wd.Chrome()
     13 wd.implicitly_wait(10)

File
~\anaconda3\envs\pgg\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:76,
in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options,
service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options,
keep_alive)
     73 self.service.start()
     75 try:
---> 76     RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     77         self,
     78         command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
     79             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80             keep_alive=keep_alive),
     81         desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82 except Exception:
     83     self.quit()

File
~\anaconda3\envs\pgg\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:157,
in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities,
browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    154 if browser_profile is not None:
    155     warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                   DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158 self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159 self._mobile = Mobile(self)

File
~\anaconda3\envs\pgg\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:252,
in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    249 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    250 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251               "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253 if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254     response = response['value']

File
~\anaconda3\envs\pgg\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321,
in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320 if response:
--> 321     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323         response.get('value', None))
    324     return response

File
~\anaconda3\envs\pgg\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:242,
in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    240         alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I think that I've declared chrome binary there:

```
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe"
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The code isn't working. What is wd? Please, edit your question

Comment: I fixed this issue with removing:

`driver.quit()`

`import chromedriver_binary`

`wd = wd.Chrome()`

`wd.implicitly_wait(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this by remove last lines:

> driver.quit()
>
> import chromedriver_binary
>
> wd = wd.Chrome()
>
> wd.implicitly_wait(10)